# ClosedXML - Could not load file or assembly exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, closedxml

I am trying to use ClosedXML to produce excel documents within an application, however, Whenevet I try to run it I receive a could not load file or assembly server error.

This is my form application 
[image: my form]

This is my Package
[image: my Package]

and this is my error when I click the import file button

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNw3V.png)

Comment: Which file or assembly can't it load?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know? If you're getting that exception, it at least specifies the starting point of the exception right?

Comment: i'm so sorry I'm a beginner in asp.net    Could not load file or assembly 'ClosedXML, Version=0.94.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Comment: @ahmedshpt ClosedXML recently changed from being a strong-named assembly to being not strong-named. This could be part of the problem. I suggest you remove all package references and re-add them. If you still want the strong-named version of ClosedXML, use the ClosedXML.Signed NuGet package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're developing for SharePoint, all used assemblies need to be strongly-named. They are deployed in the GAC, which is only possible for signed assemblies.

More info in this post: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62242/gac-and-signing-assembly-with-strong-name

You can change the NuGet reference to be **ClosedXml.Signed**, the signed version of ClosedXml.

Comment: thanks rickvdbosch : i change the reference to ClosedXml.Signed but nothing changed  can you help me please

Comment: You should give some more relevant information. What error are you getting?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'ClosedXML, Version=0.93.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd1eb21b62ae805b' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: You should probably remove the explicit `ClosedXML` reference, Clean the solution, add the `ClosedXML.Signed` reference. Then rebuild the solution and try that again. Also, if you're deploying to another machine for testing, make sure you remove everything there before deploying the new version.

Comment: thanks   rickvdbosch  i install closedxml.signed but same error