# How can I use the Signed version of ClosedXML ? (ClosedXML.Signed)

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, nuget-package, closedxml

I am using ClosedXML in my project. I needed to sign my project, but the ClosedXML NuGet appears to be unsigned : 
`Referenced assembly 'ClosedXML, Version=0.94.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.`

Following this question ([ClosedXML - Could not load file or assembly exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539770/closedxml-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-exception/53544131#53544131)), i have replaced the ClosedXML NuGet with its .Signed version.

My problem is : `using ClosedXML.Excel;` doesnt work anymore. Having only the NuGet "ClosedXML.Signed" doesnt allow me to make any reference to anything close to "ClosedXML".

Question is : How can I use the Signed version of ClosedXML ?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem was** : the .csproj didn't have the reference, despite nuget being added in the project (right click, nuget, ..).

**Solution was** : to delete the entire Package folder, i also deleted the bin folder to be sure, delete the nuget from the project, and close Visual Studio. Then reopen Visual Studio, add the new nuget (ClosedXML.Signed, in this case) and reload all nugets.

After those steps, when checking the .csproj, the reference was there.
Maybe a few of these steps were too much, but that is how i made it work.